# converting the file format using shell script

Tags: shell

i wanted to convert the format of all image files in a folder using the following shell script. My idea is to use the base name of the filename and using the same for naming the  file to be converted. I gathered these lines from internet and could not meet my requirement. Thank u all.

```
for f in *.eps
do
 echo "converting format....."
 filename=`basename ${f}`   
 fbase=`$filename | cut -d'.' -f1`  
 extn = ${fbase}.png  
   convert -geometry 1000x1000 -density 300 -trim ${f} $extn
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.eps
do  
  new=${f/eps$/png}
  echo Converting $f to $new
  convert -geometry 1000x1000 -density 300 -trim "$f" "$new"
done
```

**Note**:

The line commencing "new=" is performing a bash substitution in the variable "f", replacing "eps" at the end of the line (i.e. $) with "png".

Comment: don't use backticks, use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: and basename can remove the suffix as well, `$ echo $(basename test.eps .eps).png`

Comment: Ok, I guess they are more trendy and do have advantages. Thank you - I have updated the answer so my, and the OP's, bad habits don't spread ;-)